# Third Party Service Callback to add cart item with customization

Tags: integration, shopify

I've been looking through the Shopify APIs looking for a way to handle a third party call back that adds customization information to shopping cart items.
I don't see any Shopping Cart endpoint in the [Shopify API Documentation](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference).

Is there any way to add custom data to a cart item via the API?

Answer (score 0):

Not via the REST API, as far as I know. You can only edit the cart from within the browser using AJAX calls. That being said, once the Order is created, you can edit that with the REST API as you see fit.